# how can I handle either-or with Rx?

Tags: system.reactive

I need to handle an either-or type situation with the Reactive-Extensions.

I have 2 events I'm receiving (A or B).  When event A comes in followed by an event B within 2 seconds I want to generate a C.  If an A is not followed by B then I'd like to generate a D.

Is there some way to express that with Rx??

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way you can do it:

```
Observable.Merge(eventA, eventB)
    .Timestamp()
    .Buffer(2 /*items*/,1 /*at a time*/)
    .SelectMany(x => {
        if (x[1].Timestamp - x[0].Timestamp < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0) &&
            x[0].Value.EventType == "A" && x[1].Value.EventType == "B") {
            return Observable.Return(new C());
        }

        if (x[0].Value.EventType == "A" && x[1].Value.EventType != "B") {
            return Observable.Return(new D());
        }

        return Observable.Empty<AnEvent>();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

SelectMany along with the overload of Timeout that returns an alternate observable should be able to do what you describe.

```
Dim obsA = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) 'whatever your source is
Dim obsB = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)) 'whatever your source is
'replace with your actual C/D generation functions
Dim final = From a In obsA
            From b In obsB.Select(Function(i) "C" & a.ToString()) _
                          .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                                   Observable.Return("D" & a.ToString())) _
                          .Take(1)
            Select b
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems fairly easy by using the built in `Amb` operator.

First define `obsC` & `obsD` like so:

```
var obsC = Observable.Return('C');

var obsD = Observable.Delay(
    Observable.Return('D'),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));
```

Now I want a "B" then "C" observable. I only want a "C" once after the latest "B". If two "B"'s occur I only want the latest one. Here it is:

```
var obsBC =
    obsB
        .Select(_ => obsC)
        .Switch()
        .Take(1);
```

Now for the final query that brings it all together with the `Amb` operator:

```
var query =
    from a in obsA
    from cd in Observable.Amb(obsBC, obsD)
    select cd;
```

My testing shows that this query works. But as with all of these things it is not clear what to do if two "A"'s come in before a "B". Could I get a "D"/"C" or a "C"/"C" or just a "D" or a "C"? Depending on the required behaviour my query may need to change.